# Where did my custom root folders go after upgrading to Macos Big Sur?

Tags: macos, filesystems, macos-big-sur

I received a notification from mac to upgrade from Catalina to Big Sur.  After upgrading over the past 5 years without requiring any modifications, I just accepted the upgrade overnight.  Today I discovered all my source code sitting in a custom folder I created called /srv are nowhere to be found.

Has anyone else noticed similar issues and if so, is there any way to recover those folders without going to the time machine, or iCloud?  I hope Mac didn't just blindly delete my root folders without warning me.  That would be quite a breach in the upgrade process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my case I found that the MacOS Big Sur upgrade moved all my folders that were previously in / were moved to

`/System/Volumes/Data`

I've moved my folders back into place.  If you are upgrading to Big Sur, be sure to back up your filesystem ahead of time and move your root level folders somewhere you can find.